# Plesk Onyx installing Owncloud / Nextcloud Error 'PHP module zip not installed'

Tags: php, plesk, owncloud, nextcloud

Today I struggled installing Nextcloud / Owncloud on my Ubuntu 16.04 Server through Plesk Onyx Version 17.5.3.

I was getting the following error message:

English:

> PHP module zip not installed. Please contact your server administrator
>   to install the module. PHP modules have been installed but are listed
>   as missing? Please contact your server administrator and ask to
>   restart the web server.

German:

> PHP-Modul zip nicht installiert. Bitte für die Installation des Moduls
>   Deinen Server-Administrator kontaktieren. PHP-Module wurden
>   installiert, werden aber als noch fehlend gelistet? Bitte kontaktiere
>   Deinen Server-Administrator und bitte um den Neustart des Webservers.

Since I did, after some experimenting, manage to get around this problem I wanted to share the solution with the community.

Read the answer below…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your domain is configured with the wrong PHP version.  In my case it was 7.0.30.
In order to change this, go to:

***Domins -> mydomain.tld -> PHP Settings -> PHP-Version***

and set this to 7.2.9

---

If 7.0.30 is the only version available, go to:

***Tools & Settings -> Updates and Upgrades -> Add Components -> Web Hosting  -> PHP Interpreter Versions***

to install other PHP versions.